# Special Purpose Tablet for Commercial Navigation app

Tags: flight-planning

I just posted a request for advice on how to find right android tablet to integrate commercial flight navigation app (e.g., iFLY) to avoid bloat, OS updates that may not be compatible, and add future WiFi integration with commercial ADS B-In data overlays (e.g., FlightBox, etc.) on the Geo-referenced moving map in the navigation app.

(Please help, I don't know how to send this request to Don Hulme.)

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Unfortunately, we don't usually answer 'shopping' questions: they're often very subjective, and answers can change quickly over time. You might like to take the [tour] if you aren't familiar with how this site works, and/or bring this up in [chat].

Comment: I assume you mean me but I don't know why you would want my advice. I don't use a tablet for flying so I don't have anything relevant to recommend. You can't direct questions to specific people because the idea is that *anyone* who knows the answer can post it.

Answer (score 3):

I wish this site would embrace this topic because it is simply an extension of aircraft avionics and navigation.

This question will probably be closed, but I think this is an important question that doesn't have any definitive answer on the internet. I recently went through the upgrade from paper charts to electronic flight bag. There is very little guidance (information overload) or standardization on this topic. However, it is helpful to look at what some of the large aviation operators use.

Several flight schools have specific recommendations for tablets. For example,

ATP Flight School recommends the iPad mini, 32 GB, and Wi-Fi + Cellular for it's flight instructors.

Directly from ATP:

> ATP recommends the iPad mini, 32 GB, and Wi-Fi + Cellular (Available
>   from Apple).

I've seen similar recommendations from other flight schools and Universities with flight programs but at the moment can't find the references (will update once I locate).

Personally, I use an iPad pro because I was informed that it has better anti-glare properties on its glass than the non-pro version of the ipad, which is important for day operations in the cockpit.

(Note, Apple lists antireflective coating on both the Pro and the Mini version of iPad but not the regular iPad).

I have run several of the Navigation apps on android and iPads and noticed that they seem to be a little better on the iPads. Some even have more features  on the iPad versus the android (i.e. WingX Pro).

Also, 32GB is more than enough (as of 2018) to run the navigation apps with all charts loaded and everything turned on including synthetic vision, assuming that it is a dedicated flight tablet and you don't have it loaded down with a bunch of other content such as videos, songs, pictures, etc. Also, you'll want to install just one navigation app, if you install multiple, and download all the charts for each one, it duplicates all the data and will use up your 32GB quickly.

I have ADS-B external antenna and it works just fine with either. The ADS-B I used creates a local wifi signal that the tablet connects to the antenna and all of the traffic and weather data is incorporated into the app. In other words, ADB-B data should work with any tablet that has wifi capabilities.

Comment: As you said, there's no "definitive answer" and that's exactly why we've avoided questions like this so far. The OP is asking for opinions ("avoid bloat") and speculation ("OS updates that may not be compatible"), among other very subjective points. But having said all that, I do see your point that this topic is valuable for many people, it's just that's it's too difficult to give a single useful answer. If you think there is a good way to handle these questions then it would be great if you can bring it up in meta.

Comment: Perhaps OP can modify question. I tried to craft my question to point to objective points such as what do major flight schools recommend, technical requirements (memory), and physical qualities of the instrument (anti-glare). Or perhaps someone can help OP by adjusting question to be more objective.

Comment: In addition, OP asks for recommendations on Android tablets, and your answer seems to recommend "get an iPad." Based on what you wrote that may be the better choice but it still seems like a bit of a non-answer.

Comment: @fooot agreed. However, I was in OPs position about a year ago. I wanted to make it work with an android tablet, but after much research and trial and error I discovered (to my chagrin) the industry standard appears to currently be the iPad. Another point which I should add to my answer is to get the cellular iPad even if you don't activate it because the GPS that comes with the Cellular iPad has GPS+GLONASS, which is excellent for a moving target such as an aircraft.

Comment: Devil07: Seeking a "pure android" OS with built in GPS and WiFi. iFLY app from G-Play meets my requirements whereas WingX for android device does not. The popular android tablet I used to evaluate the two apps did not permit deletion of android 7.0 after it was downloaded. ADS B In boxes are available, but first need to fly with my own tablet + Nav app.

Comment: @AQuillen is there a reason why it must be "pure android?" You may want to try contacting the developer of the app you are using, and ask them for list of compatible android hardware. Then use that information to narrow your search. Or, if you know the technical specs that you require of the "pure android" tablet you could go to a IT related forum and ask for guidance on tablets with your specific technical requirements. Good luck!